# Current Earth sun map as a wallpaper

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, desktop-customization

Is there any software available for Ubuntu like [Desktop Earth](http://desktop-earth.en.softonic.com/)? It is actually more than wallpaper. It updates the sun map as the time of day passes.

[image: Screenshot from Windows]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe by using a script scheduled with cron to uses [**xplanet**](http://xplanet.sourceforge.net/) to generate the required view ("-num_times 1") and sets the generated image as a wallpaper?

*Edit*: [this tutorial](http://rbrusu.com/xplanet-desktop-wallpape.html) describes actually very well what I was thinking of.

Comment: Tutorial site is dead. "This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 2):

[Desktop Earth for ubuntu](http://www.anxurweb.com/2009/09/21/ubuntu-linux-impostare-come-sfondo-limmagine-della-terra-in-tempo-reale/)

Comment: Seems to be in Italian. Here's the version run through Google Translate: http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=it&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anxurweb.com%2F2009%2F09%2F21%2Fubuntu-linux-impostare-come-sfondo-limmagine-della-terra-in-tempo-reale%2F

Answer (score 0):

I made this app a short while back which may interest you

http://realtimesunlightwallpaper.weebly.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.